# JQuery queue/delay() inside each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay, each

I would like this function to delay each animation inside the each function. That is one after the other. At the moment they all come through together.

```
$('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(1000).animate({left: bounceoffset, top:-8, opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:600, queue:true});
            bounceoffset += 160;
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

the block/function you pass to `each` can accept the counter/index as first argument:

```
$('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').each(function(i){
  delay = (i + 1) * 1000
  $(this).delay(delay).animate({left: bounceoffset, top:-8, opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:600, queue:true});
  bounceoffset += 160;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DoAnimation(items, delay, bounceOffSet) {
    $(items[0]).animate({left: bounceoffset, top:-8, opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:600, queue:true})
        .delay(delay)
        .promise()
        .done(function() {
            items.splice(0, 1);
            if (items.length > 0)
            {
                DoAnimation(items, delay, bounceOffSet + 160);    
            }            
    });       
}

var items = $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li');

DoAnimation(items, 1000, 0);
```